# the reason: python string assignments accidentally change '\b' into '\x08' and '\a' into '\x07', why Python did this?

Tags: python, string

Had two answers and some comments, mentioned another question, but all had not provided REASON, why Python did this changes? such as '/b' is '/x08' is just the result, but why?
Cheers.

I try to add this path"F:\big data\Python_coding\diveintopython-5.4\py"
into sys.path, therefore, the code under it could be imported directly.

after using : `sys.path.append('F:\big data\Python_coding\diveintopython-5.4\py')`

I found I had this path inside sys.path: 'F:\x08ig data\Python_coding\diveintopython-5.4\py'

I then tested using the following code:`mypath1='F:\big data\bython_coding\aiveintopython-5.4\ry'`

the mypath1 now is : `'F:\x08ig data\x08ython_coding\x07iveintopython-5.4\ry'`

all the '\b' changed into '\x08' and '\a' changed into '\x07'

I searched for a while, but still can not find the reason, could you please check it out and any feedback or help will be appropriated. 
Many thanks.

Comment: You need double backslash to escape the backslash

Comment: Not just 'accidentally'. Quite on purpose. Use raw strings or double your backslashes or use forward slashes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to import a file in python 3.3.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758217/how-to-import-a-file-in-python-3-3-3)

Comment: Had two answers and some comments, mentioned another question, but all had not provided REASON, why Python did this changes? such as '/b' is '/x08' is just the result, but why?
Cheers.

Comment: @T.C updated my answer below with a bit more info

Answer (score 17):

Your strings are being escaped. Check out the docs on [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html):

> The backslash () character is used to escape characters that
>   otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself,
>   or the quote character. String literals may optionally be prefixed
>   with a letter `r' or`R'; such strings are called raw strings and use
>   different rules for backslash escape sequences.

This is a historical usage dating from the early 60s. It allows you to enter characters that you're not otherwise able to enter from a standard keyboard. For example, if you type into the Python interpreter:

```
print "\xDC"
```

...you'll get `Ü`. In your case, you have `\b` - representing backspace - which Python displays in the `\xhh` form, where `hh` is the hexadecimal value for 08. `\a` is the escape sequence for the ASCII bell: try `print "\a"` with your sound on and you should hear a beep.

Comment: Many thanks for your insightful reply, I will spend time t understand the link you provided.

Answer (score 10):

Escape sequence `\a`, `\b` is equivalnt to `\x07`, `\x08`.

```
>>> '\a'
'\x07'
>>> '\b'
'\x08'
```

You should escape `\` itself to represent backslash literally:

```
>>> '\\a'
'\\a'
>>> '\\b'
'\\b'
```

or use raw string literals:

```
>>> r'\a'
'\\a'
>>> r'\b'
'\\b'
```