# Pygame can't load image and the error message doesn't show the same file

Tags: python, image, pygame

I'm trying to import a background image in my pygame program. But I can't load the background file.
Code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,480))

pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

walkRight = []
walkLeft = []

for i in range(1, 9):
    walkRight.append(pygame.image.load('D:\TRAN MINH TRI\C\Downloads\Pygame-Tutorials-master\Pygame-Tutorials-master\Game\R'+str(i)+'.png'))

for i in range(1,9):
    walkLeft.append(pygame.image.load('D:\TRAN MINH TRI\C\Downloads\Pygame-Tutorials-master\Pygame-Tutorials-master\Game\L'+str(i)+'.png'))


#walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'), pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'), pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
#walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'), pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'), pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load("D:\TRAN MINH TRI\C\Downloads\Pygame-Tutorials-master\Pygame-Tutorials-master\Game\backg.jpg")
char = pygame.image.load("D:\TRAN MINH TRI\C\Downloads\Pygame-Tutorials-master\Pygame-Tutorials-master\Game\standing.png")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bulletSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('bullet.wav')
hitSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('hit.wav')

music = pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

The error

> bg = pygame.image.load("D:\TRAN MINH TRI\C\Downloads\Pygame-Tutorials-master\Pygame-Tutorials-master\Game\backg.jpg")
>   pygame.error: Couldn't open D:\TRAN MINH TRI\C\Downloads\Pygame-Tutorials-master\Pygame-Tutorials-master\Gamackg.jpg

The file the error report isn't the same image file.

Answer (score 0):

use double back slashes in path of the file you gave.

```
pygame.image.load("D:\\TRAN MINH TRI\\C\\Downloads\\Pygame-Tutorials-master\\Pygame-Tutorials-master\\Game\\backg.jpg")
```

you are getting issue because of character sequence ***\b***

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961145/the-reason-python-string-assignments-accidentally-change-b-into-x08-and/22961200) might help you. The issue is that your string is being escaped by python.