lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError for Korean Charachters
I am trying to parse https://api.lever.co/v0/postings/matchgroup?mode=xml but I am getting the error lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: CData section not finished. It seems like the issue is being caused by the data having Korea characters.
import lxml.etree                                                                                             
import io                                                                                                     
import requests
url = "https://api.lever.co/v0/postings/matchgroup?mode=xml"
r = requests.get(url)
f = io.BytesIO(r.content)
parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(recover=False)                                                                                                                                                             
tree = lxml.etree.parse(f,parser) # Raises lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError

I can change recover to True but then some of the entries would be missing.

That document is marked as not well formed even by the browser so whatever the reason, it's broken. Most probably an structure problem rather than international characters.

There are XML files that I am able to parse using lxml in Python that the Chrome and Firefox parsers fail to parse

In this case the file is broken due to a non-printable x08 character (^H)
to fix it:
f = io.BytesIO(r.content.replace(b"\x08", b""))


Should it not better replaced by \b ? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22961219/20851944

@Hermann12 non printable characters are no allowed in xml. \b would change its representation only.

If I give print('\x08') in my Jupyter, it will print a little square `` what in Korea could be a valid sign, maybe. But I am not an expert.
